# discord.py - AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'PCMVolumeTransformer'

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code for changing bot's volume in the voice channel and an error occurred.

```
class vol(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'PCMVolumeTransformer'
```

How to fix this problem?
P.S. I have downloaded discord.py and discord.py[voice] module. (version of 0.16.12)

Comment: Version 0.16.12 is the `async` branch, which does not have `PCMVolumeTransformer`. You need to update to newest version (also known as `rewrite`) if you wish to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As Benjin said in a commment, V0.16.12 is part of the old `async` branch, which does not have `PCMVolumeTransformer`. You need to update to the newest version, V1.2.0A (also known as discord.py-rewrite) if you wish to use that command.